# How to ensure only one batch can query oracle table in a multiple instances environment?

Tags: java, database, oracle

my project has a requirement to send SMS to certain kind of customers periodically, let's say every two days.

The customer information are stored in a table in Oracle DB. Every two days a scheduler in Spring Boot queries the table, sends out the SMS and then updates the table to indicate that SMS has been sent. This solution is OK enough in a single instance production environment.

But the thing is, in reality, the Production environment has four instances. Thus there are 4 instances of the scheduler running every two days. If more than one instance query the table at the same time, the customer could get more than one SMS.

May I know if there is a proper solution to prevent another batch from querying the table if one is doing so? Only if a batch finishes updating the table other batches can continue.

I am just thinking if a lock on the batches is feasible. Let's say if batch 1 is querying the table, then batch 2 3 4 are not able to access the table until batch 1 released.

Answer (score 0):

You can create conditional on property scheduler. And then  override that property in properties file at server where instance deployed. So, your scheduler bean will be only on instances where property match condition.

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "batch.", value = "enable")
```

In prop file at server add property with bool value you need:

```
batch.enable: false
```

link to spring scan property rules: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: Thx Roman. But if doing so, the batch on only one instance is working, which is not the intention of failover by setting four instances in production environment.

Comment: I think the best solution is to create service with all logic that your batch need. And schedulers will call the service methods for a job. Service will queue jobs, and will make them successively.